# Jenkins Pipeline Choices attributes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I was under the impression that the Jenkins pipeline choices syntax supported only a static newline-separated list of options and does not currently support dynamic population as the result of a groovy function (returning a map, say).

However, doing some reading on .net core I found [this](https://devblog.xero.com/ci-cd-with-jenkins-pipelines-part-1-net-core-application-deployments-on-aws-ecs-987b8e032aa0) post.

I was particularly interested in a section of one of the pipeline code extracts:

```
parameters {
    choice(choices: services, description: 'Name of the ECS service to deploy', name: 'serviceName')
    choice(choices: services, description: 'Name of Docker image to update', name: 'imageName')
    string(defaultValue: 'Tag to deploy', description: 'Docker image tag', name: 'tag')
}
```

1. Where and how does the `services` variable get set / populated?
2. What is `services` type?  Is it a map of some sort (value and description)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `services` variable here is most probably either a string with newlines (`services = "choice a/nchoice b"`) or a list (`services = ["choice a", "choice b"`]. Both work these days.

<del>I think you can set the variable in the `environment` directive and then use it in `parameters`</del> [in deed the `environment` version does not work] or (probably evil) outside of the `pipeline`:

```
List<String> CHOICES = ["a", "b", "c"]

pipeline {

    agent any

    options {
        timestamps()
    }

    parameters {
        choice(name: 'CHOICE', choices: CHOICES, description: 'Who to greet?')
    }

    stages {

        stage("test") {
            steps {
                echo params.CHOICE
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I once used this to get all labels of a Docker images on our registry, to choose which one should be deployed. There are multiple issues with this:

1. This is AFAIK completely undocumented, so it might just eventually stop working.
2. The code is executed every when the Jenkinsfile is read. It configures the job, so the parameters are changed for the *next* build. So in my case, I only got the labels which were existing during the last build, not the currently existing ones.

Comment: Thanks @Michael,  Do you know where and how it gets set?  Is it dynamically created as the result of a groovy function?

Comment: @AndrewGray Just added an answer to the first part of your question. I need to check my code examples for the exact syntax, but there are hacks to basically create a global variable.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, Would that work? I thought in the pipeline execution lifecycle parameters evaluated before environment variables were assigned.

Comment: @AndrewGray as I said, I'm not 100% sure about the environment. I'll update the answer after I checked.

Comment: @AndrewGray I updated my answer. In my opinion this is the most probable way your found example works.